# How to 3D plot?

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, 3d

I'm having trouble letting the `xi` and `yi` ranges include anything but positive integer values because of the way I am storing data in the matrix (x and y values corresponding to the slot they are stored in), but I can't figure out a more clever way of doing it. Could someone please help me out? I'd like to be able to let `xi = -30:30` and `yi = -30:30`.

```
function test3

f = @(x,y) y*sin(x) + sqrt(y);

    function p
        xi = 1:30;
        yi = 1:30;

        pts = zeros(size(xi,2),size(yi,2));
        for x = xi
            for y = yi
                pts(x,y) = pts(x,y) + f(x,y);
            end
        end
        surf(xi,yi,pts)
    end
p
end
```

Actual code that I'm working on:

```
function Eplot(z, w, R, Psi)
        ni = 0:2:4;
        mi = 0;
        xi = -30:30;
        yi = -30:30;

        pts = zeros(size(xi,2),size(yi,2));

        for n = ni
            for m = mi
                for x = xi
                    for y = yi
                        pts(x,y) = pts(x,y) + utot(z, x/10^4, y/10^4, n, m, w, R, Psi);
                    end
                end
            end
        end
        surf(xi,yi,pts)
    end
Eplot(zi, wi, Ri, Psii)
```

Comment: Why did you make a sub-function `p`? And why do `pts(x,y)+f(x,y)` when `pts(x,y)` will always be zero every time you do this?

Comment: oh, good question ... Because I was actually trying to get this to work on a more complicated function, so those are just some parts of it that were left over. I'm actually still trying to figure out how to get your solution to work with what I have >.< ... I posted the actual code, as you can see, each point is actually a linear combination of function at different `n` and `m` values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `meshgrid` (as stated in the documentation for `surf`) and write your function `f` to use element-by-element operations so that it can take matrix input.

```
f = @(x,y) y.*sin(x) + sqrt(y);
xi = -30:30;
yi = -30:30;
[x,y]=meshgrid(xi,yi);
surf(xi,yi,f(x,y))
```

(Also, I hope you don'y really want to plot `sqrt(y)` for negative values of `y`)

If you can't write your function in such a way that allows you to give it vector arguments, then your `for` loop is a reasonable method, but I would write it like this:

```
f = @(x,y) y.*sin(x) + sqrt(y);
xi = -30:30;
yi = -30:30;
pts=zeros(length(xi),length(yi));
for ii=1:length(xi)
    for jj=1:length(yi)
        pts(ii,jj)=f(xi(ii),yi(jj));
        %// If `f` has more variables to iterate over (n, m, etc.) and sum, 
        %// do those loops inside the ii and jj loops
        %// I think it makes the code easier to follow
    end
end
surf(xi,yi,pts)
```

Comment: Perfect! I completely forgot about meshgrid >.> ... whoops +.+ ...thanks for reminding me! And yeah, I meant to say real(...) XD haha